# emacs: force ido-mode to forget history

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wonder if I can keep ido from not remembering my history and only show completions for files that are in the current directory when I am searching for a file. I understand that this history feature is useful at times, but I often end up editing the incorrect file because I think I am editing file called 'abc.txt' in the current directory but in fact I am editing the file by the same name in another one that I previously visited (often happens when there is not an 'abc.txt' in the current directory, as I mistakenly assume). From reading the ido.el file I thought to set in my .emacs file (also evaluated these expressions in running emacs instance):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(ido-enable-last-directory-history nil)
 '(ido-record-commands nil)
)
```

and deleted a file called .ido.last in ~/, but still it remembers some previous files I've visited before making these changes. How can I purge my previous history, and I am not entirely sure what the difference between the two variables above are but seems to have done the trick to keep ido from remembering files I visit in the future?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, I must have had another instance of emacs running when I tried deleting ~/.ido.last before - deleting ~/.ido.last seems to work, and the commands above keep it from remembering the new ones!)

Comment: Please make your comment an answer, and mark your own answer as the accepted answer so this doesn't continue to look like an unanswered question for people looking to help.

Comment: Sorry, did not know that part about SO etiquette.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting ~/.ido.last and setting the variables as above appears to keep ido from searching files visited in the past.

**Edit:** Actually, the full customization for this task would be

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(ido-enable-last-directory-history nil)
 '(ido-record-commands nil)
 '(ido-max-work-directory-list 0)
 '(ido-max-work-file-list 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me all the time.  Given I am in directory `/path/to/dir` and I try to edit `abc.txt`, `(ido-find-file)` will "helpfully" pop me over to `/somewhere/else/abc.txt` if `/path/to/dir/abc.txt` doesn't exist and `/somewhere/else/abc.txt` does.

In this situtation, `CTRL-F` in the minibuffer when in the middle of an `(ido-find-file)` reverts to the usual behavior of `(find-file)`, so I can force Emacs to edit `/path/to/dir/abc.txt`, dammit.

Comment: It's really helpful to me!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length` to `-1` disables automatic directory switching.